# SQL*Loader-2026: the load was aborted because SQL Loader cannot continue

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am newbie to oracle sql loader. My requirement is to collect data file from user and insert to the table using sql loader.

I run SQL Loader it was working file in very first time. Records are inserted into the database.

After that I tried the same thing i will get the below error

> ORA-26026: unique index SELVA.PK_TEMP_TABLE initially in unusable state
>   SQL*Loader-2026: the load was aborted because SQL Loader cannot continue.

Answer (score 0):

> #### 26026, 0000, "unique index %s.%s initially in unusable state"
>
> **Cause:**  A unique index is in IU state (a unique index cannot have
>              index maintenance skipped via SKIP_UNUSABLE_INDEXES).
>   **Action:** Either rebuild the index or index partition, or use
>               SKIP_INDEX_MAINTENANCE if the client is SQL*Loader.

You have to rebuild or skip the index `SELVA.PK_TEMP_TABLE`.

Comment: What does this mean please `SQL*Loader-2026` ?